# input date from mysql table not showing

Tags: php, mysql

date from below input box is stored in mysql table.
code is as follows

and form code is

```
<form method="POST" name="frmwo1" action="">

    <input type="date" name="txtwodt" onchange="validatedate(document.fmwo.txtwodt)" value="<?php echo $pwodt; ?>"/>
</form>
```

however when I retrieve same date from mysql table through select query 
and wants to show in above input box using assign statement as below it is not working

my code for getting values from mysql table is as follows

```
$sql= "Select wono,wodt from WOHDR ";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn)) 
{
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
$get=mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get))
{

    $pwodt = date("d/m/Y",strtotime($row['wodt']));  
}
```

Comment: provide code you have done

Comment: ie) post the Query u made.. and get better help

Comment: Are you getting date value from SQL table

Comment: in sql table value in date field i.e. wodt is there as 2015-01-26 00:00:00

Comment: I checked my select query it is working and in assign statement as follows  $pwodt = date("d/m/Y",strtotime($row['wodt'])); it also works but in form input tag it do not shows